# window.location.href and startsWith

Tags: javascript, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I have the following JavaScript running in Chrome (demo only)

```
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url + ": " + url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1'));
```

If the url is `http://127.0.0.1` and the startsWith returns true as expected. However, if the url is

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

startsWith returns **false**. Anybody knows why?

On the other hand, if I have this:

```
var url= "http://127.0.0.1:3000"; //straight string
console.log(url + ": " + url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1'));
```

startsWith returns true as expected.

How to make startsWith return true for the following code when url is `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

```
   var url = window.location.href;
   console.log(url + ": " + url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1'));
```

**Update 1**

This is the complete code:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var url = window.location.href;
        console.log(url + ", " + url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1'));
    </script>
</head>
```

This is the result in Console

[image]

The server is Tomcat (but I don't feel it is server related). The code runs in Windows 10.

**Update 2**

Updated code to print the type of `window.location.href`. Here is the updated code:

```
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url + ", " + (typeof url) + ", " + url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1'));
```

Here is the printout:

[image]

The type is string.

**Update 3**

The reason why I am using port 3000 is because I use "gulp + browsersync" to see how my page looks like and 3000 is the default port of browsersync. Could this be an issue?

**Update 4**

Tried the following code to reveal whether there is any hidden characters.

```
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url + ", " + (typeof url) + ", " + url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1'));
console.log(Array.from(url).map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)));
```

Still got false `url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1')`. Total of 22 characters, which matches `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`. See this screenshot

[image]

**Update 5**

It seems to be the issue of the "gulp + browser sync". I stopped this tool and restarted Tomcat at port 3000. Then `url.startsWith('http://127.0.0.1')` returns true as expected for `http://127.0.0.1:3000`. The mystery is resolved (about what caused this issue).

If you do front-end work, I strongly recommend using this tool. Very cool.

**Final Update**

This issue is resolved and it was caused by **gulp + browser sync** I use for dev work. You can see the updates in this post to see how it was found to be the cause.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. I used `npx serve` which serves an index html file containing nothing but the first example code in a script element. Using `127.0.0.1:5000` the console logs `true`.

Comment: When you console.log url when you are at http://127.0.0.1:3000, does it print out http://127.0.0.1:3000, or does it print something else?

Comment: ```var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url);```
How is the url logged in console?
Maybe isn't it 'http://localhost:3000'?

Comment: @Illusion705 and istar, I posted screenshot.

Comment: Try using `npx serve .` instead of tomcat. See if you can replicate what I see?

Comment: Could you print out the type of url just so that we can confirm that it is a string? It should be, but I just want to be absolutely sure since I can't really think of any other reason this could be happening.

Comment: @Illusion705, I considered that too. I tried different handling to `window.location.href`, but still got false.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I believe you did your test through `npx serve` and got expected result. I never touched `npx serve`. Thank you!

Comment: Cannot replicate it either. Just to be sure, could there be hidden symbols? Did you try to construct a new string object from window.location.href and try it again?

Comment: So it's a server issue? Strange. I'd love to know what the actual cause of this behaviour was

Comment: @Illusion705, I did a test as you suggested. The type is string.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, that is what I am thinking now. Please see my updates to the post.

Comment: @progmem, I tried `new String(window.location.href)`, but still got false.

Comment: @curious1 You should try logging `console.log(Array.from(url).map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))`. See if that logs any character codes that are different from what you're expecting.

Comment: well on my mobile device it's showing true where i used express server.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, you are right. It is kind of server issue. Please see my latest update. Thanks!

Comment: @JLRishe, I did your test. The issue was caused by the browser sync I use for dev.

Comment: Why don't you just check `window.location.port.length === 0`?